# How to make these simple and beautiful?

Tags: java, refactoring

When I put a `(KEY, VALUE)` into a map such as `Map<String, List<String>>`, and I want to check if the KEY is existed first to decide if I have to make a new List, usually My Java Code looks like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> example = new HashMap<>();
public void put(String k, String v){
    if(example.containsKey(k)){
        example.get(k).add(v);
        return;
    }
    List<String> vs = new ArrayList<>();
    vs.add(v);
    example.put(k,vs);
}
```

It doesn't looks very nice. Is there any way to make it more simple and more beautiful?

Comment: If you have Guava, use a `Multimap`.

Comment: Or the Apache Commons one: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html#MultiValueMap%28%29

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks, Guava is amazing.

Comment: @ricemaster since the release of Java 8 many features of Guava are redundant. A Multimap can be built in a couple of lines of code with `Map.computeIfAbsent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<String>> example = new HashMap<>();
public void put(String k, String v){
    if (!example.containsKey(k)){
        example.put(k, new ArrayList<>();
    }
    example.get(k).add(v);
}
```

Arguably, this is slightly wasteful - requiring you to get the list you just put - but to my eye it is much cleaner and more expressive.

Comment: Not only that but it involves two `get` operations and a `put`. In any non-trivial environment this should be avoided.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The vast majority of our environments are trivial, and if these additional operations are critical, you've probably got problems you need to solve at a higher level.  There are certainly circumstances where I would be concerned with the performance of this approach, but for day-to-day use I prefer its clarity.

Comment: For an efficient and clear day to day use, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28380497/2071828).

Answer (score 5):

If you have Java 8 you can write this as one line:

```
example.computeIfAbsent(k, key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(v);
```

This uses a lambda, so the `new ArrayList` is *only* created if required.

(`k` and `key` need to have different names, as they are different variables)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use other libraries, or java 8, you could wrap the whole map and construct in a class of you own.

With your own class you:

1. Confine the messiness to one place.
2. Hide the face you are using a Map behind the scenes.
3. Have a place to move any additional logic to.